# Servo motor speed and torque

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, servo, robot

From what I've read the speed is controlled based on the supplied power voltage, or using delay on arduino code, how about the torque, is there a way to make the servo motor change the torque ? like torque(0) it goes lose and any eternal force can turn the motor, torque(max value) to apply max torque to achieve the needed angle?

**Edit 1**:
I'm planning to use one of those KRS-2552RHV ICS

**Edit 2** : I've done a little research after reading the comments and it seems like I will need to create a different controller or motor driver circuit to be able to change the speed using pulse width modulation, that way the speed will be controlled with pulses and the torque would be controlled with the intensity of the current

Comment: which servo motor are you talking about?

Comment: normal servo motors available nowdays that you can turn based on degrees, I'm planing to get these KRS-2552RHV ICS

Comment: Put that extra information in the question, with a link to its datasheet.

Comment: What is your actual goal here?   If you want to control torque rather than position you will need entirely different parts... but why do you want that?

Comment: I've done a little research about what you mentioned, and it seems like I will need to create a different controller or motor driver circuit to be able to change the speed using pulse width modulation, that way the speed will be controlled with pulses and the torque would be controlled with the intensity of the current, is it correct ?

Answer (score 3):

A servo motor is more a motor that is controlled in a particular way than it is a type of motor. In general, motor speed is related to voltage and motor torque is related to current. However voltage and current can not each be controlled independently, just as speed and torque can not be controlled independently, There must be coordination between current and voltage and between speed and torque. In addition, controlling motor torque is largely about controlling the available torque. The reaction of the load is just as important. When you mention "needed angle," that raises the question angle with respect to what?

Comment: thank you for the answer, I think the angle can be set from 0 to max depending on the servo motors, the one I mentioned in comment which is KRS-2552RHV ICS, has the max of 270°
So if I set a fixed voltage and change the amperage, that should chnage the torque, right? (and like you mentioned, yes the speed might slow down based on the loads)

Comment: It seems like you have components that are designed to work together. In that case, what you are doing is more at the system level. The system response to your command should be described in literature for the system. Your assumption seems likely correct, but I have no specific knowledge of that.